# how do I decrease font size in Eclipse (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux-mint, gtk, eclipse

How do I decrease the font size of tabs' title bar (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my4qA.png)  )? I use Eclipse Mobile Juno, and Linux Mint 13 Mate.

I tried both going to Eclipse Preferences and Mate preferences.
The mate preferences worked but only the font family changed, the size did not.

Comment: A quick search brings this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-eclipse-for-java-text-editors

Comment: This looks like a Java question, not like a Unix question.